# iOS - Open source Image Slide library with Pan Zoom Gestures

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Is there any ios library for iphone that supports sliding UIImageView in full view plus supports panning and zooming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once implemented this one https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser. It works pretty good!